# Why $adjacent = OP^2+OQ^2-PQ^2$ and $hypotenuse = 2OP\cdot OQ$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to follow this proof:

> [image]

In the very end where they apply the cosine formula to $\triangle POQ$, I suspect he is using the basic definition:

$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$$

But I can't figure out why $adjacent = OP^2+OQ^2-PQ^2$ and $hypotenuse = 2OP\cdot OQ$. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rearrangement of the law of cosines, which holds for any triangle with sides $a,\, b,\, c$:
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$$
where $C$ is the angle opposite side $c$. Therefore,
$$\cos(C)=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}.$$